# Continuous Integration with Google Code (C# Application)

Tags: c#, continuous-integration

My team and I are hosting our project's repository on Google Code. We would like to have a Continuous Integration setup so that when modifications are made, it tries to build the project and run the tests to make sure that everything's okay. From what I hear, a solution to this is to have an external machine listen to the repository for changes, then grab the updated files and try to build it, etc.

My question is how to set up this scenario with a Google Code repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use something like TeamCity, you can setup your source control root to point to the SVN repository hosted on GoogleCode.

This is usually something like http://yourproject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk (assuming you created a trunk for you main line of code).

For example, our link for one of our open source projects is: http://masstransit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

No authentication is needed, and you setup the VCS root as part of creating a project in TeamCity.

Comment: Yep, we have a trunk directory. At work we've used CruiseControl.NET, but I've always wanted to give TeamCity a try. I'll give it a go.

Comment: We used CC.NET before TeamCity came out, and then started using TeamCity for all new projects (including Java, Ruby, and C#) and it has worked wonderfully.